# Is there a python code that converts an MP3 file into a dataframe containing the following columns ( [seconds], [Frequnecy])?

Tags: python, mp3, frequency, audio-player

I am looking for a code which I can pass a song (PM3 file) and it reads the file and find out what the frequenncy of the frequency per second is. I hope it is as simple as it sounds like :D

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48971917/12412938) answer may help you to accomplish that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by frequency you mean sample rate, you could use [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub).

So:

```
from pydub.utils import mediainfo
info = mediainfo("/path/to/file.mp3")

print(([info['duration']], [info['sample_rate']]))

>>> (['10.044000'], ['44100'])
```

Comment: Thank you bromate for your answer! By frequency I meant in Hz. Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes, that is in Hz. Could you then flag my answer as 'Best answer' so this post is solved